# Example of topologically transitive dynamical system with invariant non-ergodic Borel measure

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, hyperbolic-dynamics, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $U \subset M$ be an open subset of a Riemannian manifold. I’m trying to find or construct an example of a topologically transitive dynamical system $f : U \to U$ for which

- $f : \Lambda \to \Lambda$ is topologically transitive, where $\Lambda = \overline{\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty f(U)}$ (i.e. there exists an orbit that is dense in $\Lambda$), and
- $\Lambda$ admits an $f$-invariant Borel probability measure $\mu$ that is not ergodic (i.e. there exists a subset $A \subset \Lambda$ for which $f(A) \subset A$ and $0 < \mu(A) < 1$) and is a physical measure (i.e. the set $\left\{x \in \Lambda : \frac 1{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\phi(f^i(x)) \to \int \phi \, d\mu \: \forall \phi \in C(M)\right\}$ has positive Lebesgue measure)

It’s been shown that if $M$ is a surface and $f:M \to M$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism, then there is only one such measure $\mu$ (in particular the unique SRB measure), and thus it must be ergodic (by the ergodic decomposition theorem). So in order for this to work, $\Lambda$ probably must be a Cantor set (or locally a product of a Cantor set with an interval), a horseshoe, or some other kind of hyperbolic attractor. Is there a known or classical example of such a dynamical system?

Comment: What rules out the full shift, say?

Comment: Your assertion about existence of a unique SRB measure is missing some hypotheses; perhaps you want to assume that f is Anosov, or at least Axiom A, in order to make that claim. But in that setting, there are lots of periodic points, hence lots of periodic orbit measures, and taking the average of one of those with the SRB gives you an invariant non-ergodic probability. In general as soon as there are multiple invariant measures you can just average two of them and get an invariant non-ergodic measure. So the only examples where all invariant measures are ergodic are the uniquely ergodic ones.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to add another condition on $\mu$, such as being physical? (ie., its set of generic points has positive Lebesgue measure.) Or having some kind of absolute continuity property?

Comment: I hadn't considered a measure supported on a periodic orbit; you're right, I should have specified that I'm interested in *physical* measures. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm still wondering about the sentence describing the surface case. I guess the fact that there is at most one such measure in that case follows from Rodriguez Hertz, Rodriguez Hertz, Tahzibi, Ures (Comm. Math. Phys. 2011) but it's not immediately clear to me where existence comes from in general. How do you know that every topologically transitive $C^{1+\alpha}$ surface diffeomorphism has an SRB measure?

Comment: I'm also wondering about your argument that uniqueness of a physical measure implies ergodicity. If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue, then the same should be true of a.e. ergodic component. Similarly for "absolutely continuous along unstables", or for "measure of maximal entropy", or for "equilibrium measure". But I don't see why a similar property should be true for physicality. A priori I don't see how to rule out a situation where $\nu$ and $\mu$ are not physical but $t\nu + (1-t) \mu$ is physical for some $t\in (0,1)$.

Comment: The Kan example -- https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1994-31-01/S0273-0979-1994-00507-5/ -- might be worth looking at, though I don't think it does exactly what you want. You might search some of the more recent papers that cite it...

Comment: Ah, I see my error. After further consideration (and reminding myself that not all physical measures are absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue), I realize that the condition I need was “absolute continuity on unstable leaves”. That should carry over to ergodic components. (Also I don’t mean to claim existence in the surface case, only that existence implies uniqueness by the result of Rodriguez Hertz et al.) Thank you for flagging the Kan example, this definitely looks useful to give me an idea of the kind of pathological phenomena that can occur.

Comment: If you're using a.c. along unstables, you may also want to require hyperbolic (a.e. point has only nonzero Lyapunov exponents) to guarantee that unstables actually exist, and that the absolute continuity also implies physicality.